# How do I generate the migration to create the initial tables?

Tags: entity-framework-migrations

I want to be able to generate my table structure entirely using migrations.
Thus the first migration should create the tables.
I thought I could achieve this by dropping the database and deleting all the migrations as well as the Configuration.
However after I enable the migrations using

```
enable-migrations
```

and create my first migration using

```
Add-Migration One
```

the up method in the migration is empty.

In the configuration I have

```
 AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
```

In the Context Creation  I have

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<Context, Configuration>());
```

If I run the application a blank database is created
I am using EF Code First 5 on Windows 7 with C# WInforms

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using

```
Add-Migration InitialCreate
```

The initial time I tried this it didn't work. I arent sure why